# With www or without www Which is better to use?

Tags: seo, domains, no-www

I have just bought a new domain `www.example.com` ....

Which is better for SEO: `http://example.com` or `http://www.example.com`

I think people will make more links starting with www and will have more backlinks for the www one. Please give your suggestions and I need to launch the website as soon as possible.

Comment: If you have plans for future expansions you don't want cookie busting and using www to properly identify the web server is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter for SEO. But most people put www in front of websites, so I suggest you to use the WWW version.

Just make sure to redirect www to non-www or the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

There are technical reasons for using www vs not-www but there is no difference for SEO. Some people like no-www because it's cleaner when printed in advertising and easier to type.